# Collection view with intrinsic height AND width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem in designing a collection view in a specific way

[image: Collection view layout]

as you can see here the layout needs to be in such a way that the height and the width of each cell needs to be dynamic.

The view should also re-arrange itself in such a way that if one cell is too long the next cell is automatically spawned in the next row.

I have seen examples of Intrinsic height in collection view but a solution for this is hard to come by. Please be sure to provide a solution for Objective C if possible.

Comment: "as you can see here the layout needs to be in such a way that the height and the width of each cell needs to be dynamic." - actually, I don't think we can see because you haven't described the specific behavior you are after. Maybe try posting an image of what you want these elements to look like, and some code showing what you've already attempted. If you want them dynamically sized, what code have you tried already to resize them?

Comment: what you want is a "TagView". Lots of different ready made classes open source easy to find via Google.

Comment: Thanks Ol Sen Tag View is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to go with `UIView intrinsicContentSize` you can not set it after initiation. Resulting in a design pattern where you have to pass NSString (or other way to tell the length) at your custom initWithFrame and use private member variables to store the size and return correct `intrinsicContentSize` and also calculate the size you want to cache depending on the strings length. And still no guarantee that UICollectionView will show up in a way you want.